# Facing a test setup failure. Fixture not found issue facing

Tags: python, automation, pytest

Facing a test setup failure. Could not access the fixture method from conftest file to the test file. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

```
   conftest.py
    class UserEndPoints:
        @pytest.fixture
        def get_user(self, url):
            response = requests.get(url)
            print("Get User: ", response)
            return response
    
    test_getuserdata.py
    URL = Routes().get_single_user.format(id=2)
    
    
    class TestUserInfo:
        def test_verifyStatusCodeGetUser(self, get_user):
            actual_status_code = UserEndPoints().get_user(URL)
            print("Get User - Actual Status Code: ", actual_status_code)
    
        def test_verifyContentGetUser(self, get_user):
            actual_content = UserEndPoints().get_user(URL.format(id=2)).content
            actual_text = UserEndPoints().get_user(URL.format(id=2)).text
            print("Get User - Actual Content: ", actual_content)
            print("Get User - Actual Text: ", actual_text)`enter code here`

test setup failed
file /usr/local/google/home/sateeshg/git-pythonselenium/apiautomation/testcases/test_getuserdata.py, line 9
      def test_verifyStatusCodeGetUser(self, get_user):
E       fixture 'get_user' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

Answer (score 0):

For fixtures in conftest.py, you should not define them inside a class.